# Redis find pattern keys that match string

Tags: redis, glob

I know that Redis has `MATCH` as a part of `SCAN` (as detailed [here](https://redis.io/commands/scan#the-match-option)) to find keys that match a glob style pattern (i.e. **sub.domain.com** could be returned from `scan 0 MATCH *.domain.com`)

My question is if there is a way to perform the reverse operation. If my keys *are* glob style patterns (i.e. ***.domain.com**  is one of the keys) how can I search to see what keys have patterns that match **sub.domain.com**?

One thought was to use `EVAL` to write a Lua script to do this, but I would think that would be fairly resource intensive? Is there some other way to approach this?

---

To make things a little clearer, here are some example keys (seperated by commas) (I'm not going to worry about the values for now as they don't really apply to this question), queries and the responses that I would expect the queries to generate:

**Keys:**
`*img.myserver.com*`, `*.mywebsite.com*`, `*www.example.com/images*`

**Queries -> expected responses (matched keys)**

`scan 0 REV-MATCH https://img.myserver.com/myimg.jpg` -> `*img.myserver.com*`

`scan 0 REV-MATCH http://www.myserver.com/otherimg.jpg` -> No matches

`scan 0 REV-MATCH http://www.mywebsite.com/blah/blah.jpg` -> `*.mywebsite.com*`

`scan 0 REV-MATCH https://www.example.com/images/old/a.jpg` -> `*www.example.com/images*`

`REV-MATCH` (Reverse Match) is a function that doesn't exist - but I'm hoping that similar functionality can be found some other way. It is possible for there to be multiple matches if two keys had glob patterns that could match the same string in some scenarios (in my use case, however, this wouldn't happen as I would always ensure the glob patterns never overlapped)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm wrong, I think that you're overthinking it. A `GET *.domain.com` (i.e. replace "sub" with "*") should do it. If unfound, continue with a `GET *.com`, and so forth until ending with `GET *`, which should be the "root" of all things.

---

## Updated answer

Ok, I see. So, no, `SCAN` isn't the way but I know of at least two other paths you can try. Give me a shout or open a new question if you run into any dead ends ;)

### The Path of Sorted Sets and Lexicographical Ranges

Go to https://redis.io/topics/indexes#lexicographical-indexes and read (may take more than one iteration, and I recommend reading the entire thing actually). Then, given your requirements, remember that you can do suffix matching by storing (and searching) the reverse in another Sorted Set.

### The RediSearch Path

Take a look at http://redisearch.io, a Redis module that implements a full search engine (autocomplete included(tm)).

**Disclaimer:** I work at Redis Labs, home of the open source Redis and provider of commercial solutions that leverage on it, including the above mentioned module (open source, AGPL licensed).

Comment: Well sure, that could work - maybe my example was misleading because I'm not just dealing with subdomains, and there might not always be a nice cutoff, (the glob pattern could be **.example.com/blah/blah** or something even longer). Either way I'm wanting to do this all in one request without having to keep trying again depending on the results of the previous request as that would introduce latency that I can't afford.

Comment: Perhaps a more detailed and lies misleading example would help here - could you add a few keys/patterns and queues with the expected answers?

Comment: See my edit - let me know if you need any further clarification. Thanks!

Comment: @ItamarHaber I am playing with mastering redisearch part 3 code and not sure how I can utilize Redisearch built in autocomplete feature. Please guide. Thanks


  [1]: https://github.com/stockholmux/mastering-redisearch/tree/chapter-3

Comment: Just contact kyle (kyle at redislabs dot com) ;)